# What would be the easiest way to use an Arduino to control a 24AC solenoid, when I only have access to 220VAC mains?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, mosfet, ac

I do also have the Arduino power supply and output pins at 5 or 3 volts to control, for example, a mosfet gate voltage.

Sorry if this is a nooby question - I am an electronics noob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arduino - component selection for controlling high-powered solenoids](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280897/arduino-component-selection-for-controlling-high-powered-solenoids)

Comment: Would I just use a transformer to get the ac from 220 to 24v?

Comment: Oh and it's not a duplicate - that guy is using a DC solenoid

Comment: There are triacs who might do the work with both positive and negative polarity, I think. Someone might correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221662/using-triac-to-control-solenoid Might help you

Answer (score 2):

You have (at least) two problems to solve.

1. You need 24VAC (or thereabouts) to power the solenoid. That problem is solved by a 220:24 VAC transformer rated for the solenoid VA (or more).
2. You need to switch either the 24VAC or the 220VAC. That can be accomplished with a relay or an SSR that is suited for **inductive** loads. Or you could make your own SSR with an alternistor and perhaps an optocoupler.
3. If you use a relay you need to power and switch the relay.
4. If you use a relay or most SSRs you should add some suppression across the load to reduce arcing. An RC snubber, for example.

A suitably AC-output SSR with isolation and rated for inductive loads is probably the easiest and safest option. Most can be driven directly from the MCU.

---

An alternative option if you have only a single solenoid to power and are willing to devote the transformer to it is to use a bridge rectifier and a MOSFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiLSb3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2/R3 are optional but somewhat reduce the likelihood you'll have certain problems. M1 should be a logic level MOSFET.

---

In some cases you can run an AC solenoid from a much lower DC voltage and it will work well enough. If you apply 24VDC to a 24VAC solenoid usually it will overheat and burn out.